# Python converting back slash to forward slash

Tags: python, copy

I'm trying to copy dir1 to dir2. Dir1 contains sub-folders and files. In the moment of copy I'm creating url like this `C:/dirA/dir1` and `C:/dirB/dir2`. As you see all slashes are forwarded. When run I get this error

```
 No such file or directory path C:/dirB/dir2\\folder1\\file.txt
```

As you see sub-folder and file have backslashes. I really do not know how to change that backslashes because when I create a paths I don't know the names of sub-folders/files. I can't post entire code because it's huge.
To copy I use `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`.

Comment: Spend a few minutes isolating the relevant part of your code, it's really not that hard

Comment: if you have the path as a string you can maybe do path.replace('/','\')

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use `os.path.normpath` on parts of your path to normalize them for current OS before you concatenate, on Windows it'll use correct slashes.

Comment: OK. Thanks, this fixed the slashes, but I'm still getting the same error. It seems like the problem was not backslashes.